# How do I send a friend request to a known user in Facebook? (Android)

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have read this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/send-requests#notifications tutorial, And I didn't understand How do I send friend request to a known user in Facebook (In Android application). I have the user id. I have been trying a lot but i came with no success.

this is my code, If someone have an advice how do I can do this it will be very helpful :)
This code presents how to do an APP request, and i want to do a friends request.

```
private void sendRequestDialog() 
{
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", "Learn how to make your Android apps social");

    WebDialog requestsDialog = (
        new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))
            .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values,FacebookException error) 
                {
                    if (error != null) 
                    {
                        if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) 
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Request cancelled", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Network Error", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        final String requestId = values.getString("request");

                        if (requestId != null) 
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Request sent",  
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Request cancelled", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }   
                }

            }).setTo("XXXXXXXXX").build();

    requestsDialog.show();
}
```

Thanks in advanced :)

Comment: that´s not a friend request, it´s an app request. afaik you cannot send friend requests with the api.

Comment: There is no way to send friend requests